# Highlighting a cell in a table when a word is included

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table in which I would like to highlight when a special character appears.
An example below.

When there is a date entered on 11.2020, the cell should not be highlighted, but when the entry 11.2020+ appears, the background of the text will change to red. How to set such a mask?

My code

```
<td>
<div style="background-color:red; color:white; font-weight:bold"><span ng-if="data.data=='11.2020'">{{data.data}}</span></div>
</td>
```

Comment: What does your data look like? How is your table rendered? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are using angularjs, not angular :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

.html

```
<td [style.color]="isValid(data.data) ? 'black' : 'red'">{{data.data}}</td>
```

.ts

```
isValid(str) {
  return !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhxd1b?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: This just validates a date, right? There are better alternatives to do that. For example `ngx-mask`. Or a date validator. I think regex is not really the best solution for that

Comment: @PsychoPflanze It checks the string. Can you please check the demo?

Comment: If the use-case is to do just that, yeah you are right. But i don't know if it's any string.

Comment: Ya, its better to create a pipe out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>
```

use else of the ngIf condition like this.
and if you have problems just read the documentation : https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask). This will automatically prevent the user from typing in a wrong date, makes for a better experience :D

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can call a function in ngClass to return classes based on your conditions. For Example:

```
<td>
 <div [ngClass]="getBackgroundColor(data.data)"> {{data.data}</div>
</td>
```

And in your component file:

```
public getBackgroundColor(value:string): string {
 if (value === "11.2020")
  return "bg.light"; // or whatever colour you want
 } else if (value.includes("11.2020")) { // or match with your regex
  return "bg.danger";
 }
  return "bg.light";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AngulaJS

```js
$scope.validate=function(data){
if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(data) == false)
  return true;

 return false;
}
```

```css
.cell-highlight{
  background-color:red;
  color:white; 
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<td>
<div ng-class="{'cell-highlight':validate(data.data)">{{data.data}}</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use your function but I don't want to work - it highlights cells.
I think I have the correct code.
I don't know yet what `.test` means in the code.

Comment: The test() method tests for a match in a string. This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.